# How to run a rails script in production env

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a script "tester.rb" in my local system and has below function

```
def getAccountUpdate(Id)
   user = User.find_by_id(Id)
   user.name = "Default"
end
```

How will i be able to run the function which is present in my local system . how will i run this function in the production rails console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your rails console using `rails c`. Write like below.

```
irb(main):001:0> def get_account_update(id)
irb(main):002:1> user = User.find_by_id(id)
irb(main):003:1> user.name = "Default"
irb(main):004:1> end
=> :get_account_update
irb(main):005:0> get_account_update(1)
```

If you want to run it in production use `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c` to start the console and write it.

If you don't want to use console and run it as a task then use Rake tasks.